# Is it possible to get search engines to index hundreds of thousands of personal profiles from my site?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing

I have a database of several hundred thousand profiles that include names, careers info, and contact info. I was thinking of creating a teaser webpage for each profile that could be indexed by search engines. But I am not sure if this is the best way. Thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like low quality content to me

Comment: You have everyone's permission to post their info?

Comment: @JCL1178 I agreed that what you said. But, is big companies like "crunchbase" get permission before publishing use information in their site?

Comment: @DamithRuwan Depends on the information. If all of the info is publicly known (e.g. web sites, social media accounts) then no.  But you mentioned contact information which leads me to think of phone numbers and email addresses and posting that without permission will get you into trouble at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Search engines will only index that many pages from your site if your site has very high reputation.   Facebook or LinkedIn could probably get that many pages indexed, but your site won't be able to.

Google doesn't like sites that publish tons of pages with very little content on each.   If you publish that many pages and then users don't find them useful, you will likely find your website punished under Google's Panda algorithm.

I would recommend testing the waters by testing out 1000 or 10,000 of the highest quality pages.   Find the ones where you have the most data and publish those first.   If you find those get search engine traffic and can satisfy the searchers that land on them, then expand from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are determined to post that, the method you describe is the way to go. Whether or not you get any traction for it is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you mean by teaser webpage. Are you actually going to show the profile data on the teaser page?

IF you mean the profile info is used as a teaser to get you to enter into your site. I'd probably start that operation by collecting a bunch of profiles into some sort of useful classification and showing larger lists of the database results. Hundreds of thousands of think little profile pages that do not lead to a directly relevant site are gonna get bounced, with negative ramifications for your whole site.

Comment: It sounds like LinkedIn. They show a partial profile (like name & basic info) but you have to logged in / connected to view everything.